# How to get react-virtualized Collection to update when re-rendered with new width and columnCount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

Here are the `cellSizeAndPositionGetter` and `render` functions for my react component.  My screen layout doesn't change when I resize the screen, but I can confirm through the console that the `width` and `state.columnCount` (used by `cellSizeAndPositionGetter`) are changing.

**Is it possible to trigger a `Collection` update following parameter change (namely, `width`)?**  Or am I doing something wrong here?

Sidenote:  `react-virtualized` `List` *does* update upon width parameter change.

```
cellSizeAndPositionGetter({index}) {
    const list = this.state.cardsList;
    const columnCount = this.state.columnCount;

    const columnPosition = index % (columnCount || 1);
    const datum = list[index]; 

    const height = datum.height;
    const width = CELL_WIDTH;
    const x = columnPosition * (GUTTER_SIZE + width);
    const y = this._columnYMap[columnPosition] || 0;

    this._columnYMap[columnPosition] = y + height + GUTTER_SIZE;

    return ({
        height,
        width,
        x,
        y
    });
}
```

...

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={styles.subMain}>
            <AutoSizer >
                {({height, width}) => {
                    console.log(`width: ${width}`);
                    console.log(`col count: ${this.state.columnCount}`);
                    return (
                        <Collection
                            cellCount={this.state.cardsList.length}
                            cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
                            cellSizeAndPositionGetter={this.cellSizeAndPositionGetter}
                            height={height}
                            width={width}
                            overscanRowCount={1}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            </AutoSizer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: (a few hours later)

I discovered a very kludgy work-around to get `react-virtualize` `Collection` to update following a width parameter change.

When the screen size changes, I remove the last element of my list of `Collection` display elements (images).  At first I tried clearing the list, but that causes obvious visual side-effects.  Now, only the final image in my display flickers weirdly when resizing the screen.

**But it would still be nice to get `Collection` to update following `width` change. :)**

Here is the code that seems to trick `Collection` into updating.  Key part is the third line of `setState` where I remove the last element.

```
updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({
        screenWidth: window.innerWidth,
        columnCount: Math.floor(window.innerWidth / (CELL_WIDTH + GUTTER_SIZE)),
        cardsList: [...this.state.cardsList.slice(0, this.state.cardsList.length - 1)] 
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    ...
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does a change in `width` mean reflowing the cells? (Do you want the size and position of cells inside of the `Collection` to change?) If so, you'll need to store a ref to the `Collection` and then call `collectionRef.recomputeCellSizesAndPositions()` when `width` changes.

`Collection` (like all other react-virtualized components) cache size and position information for performance. You need to explicitly clear those caches if things change. See [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized#pure-components) and [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Collection.md#recomputecellsizesandpositions).